# AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to use this header **#import < AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h >** in theos tweak, but i get this error:

> AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h: not such file or directory

i also add the AVFoundation framework to the makefile.

if i do **#import < AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>**  work fine, but i need this header **AVCaptureDevice.h**

help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My apologies, I completely missed the lower part of your post for some reason.
Just import the whole AVFoundation framework. It will include the AVCaptureDevice header for you.

---

For Theos projects, you need to add the frameworks to your makefile.

Look for this line (if it doesn't exist, add it manually):

```
*YOUR_PROJECT_NAME*_FRAMEWORKS
```

There's where you add any public framework you want to use. Suppose your app is called "myVideo" and you want to add the AVFoundation framework, you would do this:

```
myVideo_FRAMEWORKS = AVFoundation
```

As an additional piece of info, if you wanted to add more frameworks you do this:

```
myVideo_FRAMEWORKS = AVFoundation UIKit
```

Comment: i alredy add the framework to the makefile, also have UIKit framework too and its not working you said make this #import <AVFoundation> ? or how i add the entire Framework to my tweak ?

Comment: What you are doing is fine. #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> will give you all the classes in the framework, including the one you want to use.

Comment: ok, but when i do that , i get 'AVCaptureDevice'  was not declared in this scope. so is like they don't import that class

Comment: Alright, I'm running out of ideas but do you actually have the AVCaptureDevice header? It's possible you got an incomplete dump of headers.

Comment: i am running theos in my iPhone 4s, so i think i dont need the headers dump.